# Multiple database connections with Python + Pylons + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pylons

I'm trying to implement the proper architecture for multiple databases under Python + Pylons.  I can't put everything in the config files since one of the database connections requires the connection info from a previous database connection (sharding).

What's the best way to implement such an infrastructure?

Comment: Have you checked out the sharding example in the SQLAlchemy source? http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/sqlalchemy/trunk/examples/sharding/attribute_shard.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylons's template configures the database in `config/environment.py`, probably with the `engine_from_config` method. It finds all the config settings with a particular prefix and passes them as keyword arguments to `create_engine`.

You can just replace that with a few calls to `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` with the per-engine `url`, and common `username`, and `password` from your config file.