# How to use multiple Sessions in a pylons app?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I've read ["Multiple database connections with Python + Pylons + SQLAlchemy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205047/multiple-database-connections-with-python-pylons-sqlalchemy) and I get how to create multiple engines using that technique, but now I'm looking for advice on how to handle the creation of `Session`s for these engines. Right now, the `Session` in my project is defined as per Pylons convention: `myapp.model.meta.Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())` and imported as `myapp.model.Session`. This works fine if there's only one engine.

What's a good, maintainable approach to defining this for multiple engines? The set of engines may change at runtime, for what it's worth, so I'd need the ability to create new `Session`s on the fly, without hard coding them into the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want choose the database backend per one request, a good option is to call `meta.Session(bind=get_engine_for_this_request())` as the first thing. That will create the session with the specified parameters. You can stick that into the BaseController if it makes sense in your case.

For multiple backends per one request the best approach depends on your specific usecase. If all the backends have the same schema, it's probably best to create multiple ScopedSessions, one for each backend. When they hold different schemas, you can create multiple MetaData objects (or Base classes in case of declarative) and bind them to the engines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bind` parameter to `sessionmaker` to bind the session to a specific connection.

See http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/sessions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker for more information.

Comment: I know how to bind sessions; this isn't news. I need to manage multiple models, associated with different sessions and engines within one application.

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I misunderstood the question. I think the answer strongly depends on your application architecture. I'd probably stash references to the sessions & bound models in a dict with the engine as the key, and use that throughout the code.